# /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory (Removed python rpms now python doesn't work and yum doesn't work)

Tags: centos, python, yum

I was uninstalling OpenSSH with the following command:

```
for i in $(rpm -qa | grep openssh);do sudo rpm -e $i --nodeps;done
```

Then for some reason, I don't know why I thought this was a good idea, I ran this command to remove python:

```
for i in $(rpm -qa | grep python);do sudo rpm -e $i --nodeps;done
```

Now when I run sudo yum update I get the following:

> bash: /bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

First line of /bin/yum reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I then checked the /usr/bin directory for python

```
ls -lha /usr/bin | grep python
```

and got back nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Search the web for the appropriate Python RPMs, download them manually eg. using `wget` or `curl` and install them manually using `rpm -i`.

From your comments I see that you have another machine with the same CentOS release, so you are lucky :). You can obtain exact information which packages to install. On that other machine, type

```
rpm -q -R yum
```

This will list all `yum` dependencies. For example, on an old release of CentOS I have access to, it lists the following:

```
/usr/bin/python
config(yum) = 3.2.29-40.el6.centos
pygpgme
python >= 2.4
python(abi) = 2.6
python-iniparse
python-sqlite
python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.0-8
rpm >= 0:4.4.2
rpm-python
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
yum-metadata-parser >= 1.1.0
yum-plugin-fastestmirror
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

You can ignore the entries that don't have `python` in their name as you didn't uninstall them. You can also ignore the `python(abi)` entry as it's just a *feature* provided by `python` package. So what is left is:

```
python >= 2.4
python-iniparse
python-sqlite
python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.0-8
rpm-python
```

Then for each of these packages run

```
rpm -q <packagename>
```

It will give you the exact filename/version of the package installed. For example, on the machine I have `rpm -q python` outputs `python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64` and `rpm -q python-iniparse` outputs `python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch`. So you have to look exactly for these filenames in CentOS repositories. You can find the addressess of the repositories in files that are located within the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory.

Download these RPM files and install them.

If `yum` still doesn't work, it is possible that Python packages depend on each other and something is still missing. Check the following on the other machine:

```
rpm -qa | grep python
```

and install all the indicated packages on the broken machine.

Comment: I found python 2.7.5 rpm and was able to install it via rpm -i.
I can now run python and get python 2.7.5 interpreter

Comment: However, when I do a sudo yum update command I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call list):
  File "/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
     yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code_True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py" line 236, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py" line 90, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py" line 161, in getOptionsConfig
    disabled_plugins=self.optparser._splitArg(opts.disabledplugins))
TypeError: _getConfig() takes exactly 1 argument (9 given)

Comment: Probably you need some additional Python modules as well.

Comment: I just ran `rpm -q -R yum` on some old CentOS I have access to and it told me that `yum` depends on packages `python-iniparse`, `python-sqlite`, `python-urlgrabber` and `rpm-python`. When you uninstalled everything python-related, you probably uninstalled them, so you need to install them again.

Comment: I actually already installed python-iniparse, python-urlgrabber, and rpm-python. I did not do python-sqlite yet however. I found python-sqlite here: `https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-sqlite&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=x86_64`. when I tried to do `rpm -ivh python-sqlite.rpm` it failed on a few two dependencies:
libsqlite3.so.0 & python(abi) = 2.4. I am having trouble finding those rpms, do you have a link to the dependencies for python-sqlite?

Comment: python(abi)=2.4 means it's a module for python 2.4, and you have 2.7.5. You must find a correct version for your system.

Comment: It's weird because when I run `rpm -q -R yum` it has a number of results but this one in particular confuses me:
`python(abi) = 2.7`

Comment: It means your `yum` requires python version 2.7.

Comment: Yet another dependency when trying to do `rpm -ivh pythonabi.rpm`, python < 2.4 is needed by pythonabi-1:2.3-3.el4.at.x86_64. I tried `rpm -ivh python2.4-2.4-1pydotorg.src.rpm` and it resulted in the following message:
`Updating / Installing...
  1. python2.4 [100%]
warning: user jafo does not exist - using root
`` group jafo does not exist`
Now it still says failed dependencies when I try to rpm install pythonabi with same message of: `python < 2.4 is needed by pythonabi-1:2.3-3.e14.at.86_64`

Comment: I would suggest you ask someone using the same CentOS version as you (maybe on some CentOS help forum?) that they give you exact versions/filenames of the RPMs you need to install.

Comment: I have another machine that is CentOS 7.9 (same as machine with issue). What command can I run to get all the .rpms needed to fix the yum issue?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include instructions.

Comment: I ran the `rpm -q -R yum` command on both servers and the output looks identical now.
On other machine with working yum, `rpm -q python-sqlite` returns python-sqlite is not installed. Broken yum server also does not have python-sqlite installed. `yum update` on broken yum server still saying same error:
`TyperError: _getConfig() takes exactly 1 argument (9 given)`

Comment: If python-sqlite is not listed by `rpm -q -R yum` then you don't have to install it. Install whatever is installed on the other machine, do not follow literally the example I have shown.

Comment: If there are still errors, you may try to do `rpm -qa | grep python` on the other machine and install all these packages, as the python packages may depend on each other, and you uninstalled all of them.

Comment: From what I can tell the results from `rpm -q -R yum` are now identical but I am still getting the original error when trying to use any command within `yum`

Comment: It's not the results of `rpm -q -R yum` that are important to be identical, it's the actual installed packages that must be identical. `rpm -q -R yum` tells you what **should** be installed for yum to work, and not what **is**. Check `rpm -qa | grep python`

Comment: I did `rpm -q python`, `rpm -q python-iniparse` for each item from the `rpm -q -R yum` results and those version matched/were install on both now. `rpm -qa | grep python` are greatly different, working yum server (server2), has over 100 items, while broken yum server (server1), has only 14 items

Comment: Something from those 100 items must be important. Try run `rpm -q -R <packagename>` on each item from `rpm -q -R yum` output, maybe you can determine what it is.